# Clarification about Dogethereum

Tags: tokens, altcoin, project-fork

Can someone explain me the Dogethereum project?

I mean, is it a token managed by a smart contract (through a bridge) or is it a full independent blockchain whose code is based on that of Ethereum, so that it is a platform for the developing of its own decentralized apps with dogethereum as currency?

Answer (score 1):

*Dogethereum is a brand-new cryptocurrency that is a decentralized cryptocurrency. It will be created on the snapshot of the popular Dogecoin. It’s going to be built on the powerful and well-respected ETH algorithm because of it’s ultra-fast transaction speed. Another reason it’s based on Ethereum’s platform is because the use of smart contracts. The main goal of the company is to push the current Doge currencies in a different direction than it’s previously been on. One of the main reasons is to eliminate the somewhat hated ASIC mining, and to give it a new type of quickness and level of ease for newbies.*

[Here](https://github.com/dogethereum/docs/blob/master/design.png) and [Here](https://github.com/dogethereum/docs/blob/master/design-eth2doge.png) you can find the design diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From the diagrams it seems to be just a ERC-20 token managed by a smart contract. So, why in the website there is a dedicated miner, a dedicated wallet "that can hold Dogx and Dogx-based tokens" and there is go-dogethereum as a node client implementation?